# Are the dragon priests in Skyrim from the base game or a DLC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've only played Skyrim with all the DLC installed, so I don't know which parts of the game were in it from the start, and which were added in DLC.

Are dragonpriests from the base game or from a DLC (if so, which one)?

Comment: Not sure what distinction you are drawing between "DLC" and "canon" here. Characters and events in official DLC are usually still considered canonical.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_%28fiction%29

Comment: I can see why the original version of this question received downvotes (unclear what you meant by canon and no punctuation or formatting), but here's an upvote after the rephrasing.

Answer (score 8):

According to the Elder Scrolls Wiki, [Dragon Priests appear](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Priest#Appearances) in both the Skyrim base game, and the Dragonborn DLC.

Answer (score 0):

Unnamed dragon priests were in the base game, as well as the eight masked priests. Once the player collected all of these masks they could use the wooden mask at Labyrinthian to obtain the final mask, Konahrik.

The Dragonborn DLC added three new masked dragon priests on Solstheim (each representing one of fire, ice and lightening), as well as a number of unmasked named dragon priests.

To the best of my knowledge, no new dragon priests were added in the Dawnguard DLC. This means all of the dragon priests in the main world (Skyrim) are from the base game, and all of the dragon priests in Solstheim are added by the Dragonborn DLC.

I hope this helps.